# How to debug a code on Logic-Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using Logic-Apps for my project now. I think it's good and easy! However, It was difficult to debug during the coding of the logic. Because I couldn't to confirm the variables or status at a middle point of the code. Usually a developer can detect the variables during the execution of program on Visual Studio. How can I debug the code on Logic-Apps? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, Logic Apps can only run on Azure, thus while you are developing a workflow, in order to debug your code, you need to run it on Azure. Once you run it, you can see the inputs and outputs of each action for that instance, including setting variable actions.

You can see [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps) how to monitor each instance and the inputs and outputs of each action.

HTH

Comment: oh, I see. I understood. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same.

Do you think logic apps just aren't utilized enough for MS to implement any sort of debugging / local moc engine capability? Or, is this more a limitation of the technology that makes that difficult?

Answer (score 0):

You can design and run the workflow locally in Visual Studio Code using this add in: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-logicapps